# Magento 2.3: How to display price for out of stock bundles

Tags: magento2.3

We have an issue where if a bundle product has options that are out of stock, it shows that the price for those products are $0.00.

How would you display the full configured bundle price regardless of stock status?

Comment: basically it should not affect the price because out of stock products will not be displayed in the option of a bundled products

Comment: Thanks, I guess what I'm trying to say is that we always want the default configured price showing so customer can see what the price is normally. The price appears discounted if a default option is out of stock

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: Not yet, still looking into it

Answer (score 0):

We have the same issue. Have you found a solution to fix this issue?